# How to avoid GLSL copy by value?

Tags: gpu, glsl

The following code:

```
layout (set = 0, binding = 0) readonly buffer TestBuffer {
    float[32] probs;
} args;

void main() {
    const float[] ps = args.probs;
}
```

creates a deep copy of the float array, i.e., it copies all the array members. I would have thought that the const qualifier would make `ps` just an alias for args.probs, just as when passing it to a function with a `const in` qualifier.

Copying the array again, like `const float[] ps2 = ps`, only copies the reference.

Is there any way to do this without runtime overhead? Of course, in the real world args is much larger and contains nested arrays of structs, so being able to reference just a small part of it is useful, but not practical due to a huge performance penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the only thing you want to do here is to create a shorter name for a longer name. That is, if `args.probs` is something like `args.foo[30].bar.whatever`, you want to refer to that particular piece of data as `ps`.

This is probably best done with a macro: `#define ps args.probs`. Now obviously, this has downsides. Macros are not lexically scoped for example; you explicitly have to `#undef` them to prevent those names from leaking out.

But GLSL doesn't have a reference system like C++, nor does it have actual pointers. So the only choice to avoid a conceptual copy (the implementation could and *should* have optimized it out) is to use a macro.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yes, that is the only thing I wanted to do, and after increasing the size of the input data substantially performance was hit badly. I then tried to just write the whole long expression at every place and things were fast again -- actually faster than before increasing the input data size! :)

It seems the copy is optimized away if the the source and destination are both declared const, but the source being a readonly buffer and the compiler doesn't get it.  I would just have hoped that there would be a more "modern" solution than resolving to macros:)

Comment: This is using MoltenVK on Macos, btw, so maybe I should try this on Linux to see how that compiler works.